# Could not able to make selection in second drop down list using python and selemium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to make selection on the second drop down list after making a selection on first drop down list

The html code used for the first is :

[image: First Drop down and its option values]

For the second drop down the html code used is :

[image: Second Drop down and its option values]

The html code for the drop down has 3 attributes namely : `id`, `style` and `class`. I want to make selection on second drop down as `INDIA`.The problem is I cant use id attribute as it is dynamic and always changes whenever i load the page and i cant be able to use class as both the drop down has same class as `StyledDropDown`.

I have used find element/elements by class and xpath but it is doing selection on the first drop down in first case and giving error in latter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have a wait for the second drop down to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `indexing` here to locate desire `dropdown`, if there is no possibility to locate using any `attribute` value of these `dropdown` as below :-

```
dropdown = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("StyledDropDown")

#now check first if length is equal to 2
if len(dropdown) == 2 :
 firstDropdown = dropdown[0]
 secondDropdown = dropdown[1]

 #now do your stuff with desire dropdown
```

Or you can also locate these `dropdown` using `xpath` with index to desire as below :-

```
#for first drop down
firstDropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(.//select[@class = 'StyledDropDown'])[1]")
```

Blockquote

```
#for second drop down
secondDropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(.//select[@class = 'StyledDropDown'])[2]")
```

Comment: Thanks you for your prompt reply, Second solution worked perfectly,how ever the first solution did not worked for me but want to understand the logic behind its functioning